# SQL count on a field which is a code

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table

```
ANSWERS 
   qId
   toggle_value
```

which records an HTML radio button value `{Yes, N/A, No, Resolved}`

Now I want to count and summarize how many yeses, nos, nas and resolved grouped by question Id.

For simplicity I started to build each individual query.

```
SELECT qId, count(*) as yes_qty FROM ANSWERS WHERE TOGGLE_VALUE='Yes' GROUP BY qId;
SELECT qId, count(*) as na_qty FROM ANSWERS WHERE TOGGLE_VALUE='NA' GROUP BY qId;
SELECT qId, count(*) as no_qty FROM ANSWERS WHERE TOGGLE_VALUE='No' GROUP BY qId;
SELECT qId, count(*) as resolved_qty FROM ANSWERS WHERE TOGGLE_VALUE='Resolved' GROUP BY qId;
```

But I really want it in one query so I can iterate over the list and display something like this ( aggregating 14 Checklists with 3 questions)

```
Q      Yes      No     NA     Resolved
1       4       10     0        10
2      14        0     0         0
3       7        0     7         0
```

I don't actually use strings for the toggle value but numbers 1=yes, 2=NA, etc... and was wondering if a better table design would have been

```
ANSWERS 
   qId
   yes_value
   no_value
   na_value
   resolved_value
```

I'd have to refactor a lot of other things if I changed the table deisgn so I was hoping to get a single query working.

Comment: I'm glad my table design is good because it would have a ripple effect on onther code if I changed it. I selected the answer that seemed the easiest to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT qId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOGGLE_VALUE='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YesQty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOGGLE_VALUE='No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoQty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOGGLE_VALUE='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NAQty,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TOGGLE_VALUE='Resolved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ResolvedQty
  FROM ANSWERS 
 GROUP BY qId
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your table design. I would personally solve this with a `SUM` and `GROUP BY` and using `CASE` clauses to create new columns.

Comment: (Ok, Nitin was faster to post the answer...)

Comment: +1 Never Mind, your answer is also conceptually correct ... Idea is to help other with what so ever little knowledge we have ...